# how to use Fresco with different http header

Tags: android, fresco

I am using the Fresco to fetch images from network. I want to using different http header in different Activity because I should fetch the images from different website. I set the http header in the `okhttpclient` and build a `ImagePipelineConfig`. How can I change the http header in different Activity? Is rebuilding a `ImagePipelineConfig` and initializing Fresco in different Activity a good way?

Answer (score 2):

As, it's already defined in the [documentation](https://frescolib.org/docs/using-other-network-layers.html). What you need to do is to write custom NetworkFetcher and pass your headers using a network interceptor installed with that NetworkFetcher.

Answer (score 1):

Re-initializing Fresco is currently not supported. We might add this at some point in the future but for now, the best approach would be to implement a simple custom NetworkFetcher that holds all of your different OkHttpClients and then forwards it to the correct one, similar to the existing [OkHttpNetworkFetcher](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/tree/master/imagepipeline-backends/imagepipeline-okhttp3/src/main/java/com/facebook/imagepipeline/backends/okhttp3).